# backtrace_symbols/backtrace_symbols_fd not working even with -rdynamic

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, backtrace

I have small program on C that I compile under ubuntu with GCC version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
I want to be able to see particular line (or function name) that caused segmentation fault.

Here is my compilation script:

```
rm -rf ./server.bin
gcc -w -c ./*.c witfy/common/list.c witfy/common/data.c witfy/common/aes.c witfy/common/sts_queue.c -fpack-struct=2 -fpermissive -I/usr/include/mysql
gcc -o server.bin ./*.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl -rdynamic
rm -rf ./*.o
```

And then, in code I use example from https://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols:

```
static void handle_signal(int signal) {
    if (signal == SIGSEGV) {
        void *array[100];
        char **strings;
        size_t size = backtrace(array, 100);        
        //backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
        strings = backtrace_symbols(array, size);
        if (strings == NULL) {
            perror("backtrace_symbols");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) printf("%s\n", strings[j]);
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(1);        
    }    
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    new_action.sa_handler = handle_signal;
    sigemptyset (&new_action.sa_mask);
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction (SIGSEGV, &new_action, NULL); 


    ...


}
```

And the only thing I get as output is:
    [0x11a68b4ac]

BTW, I found that I might need addr2line, but it also doesn't provide any info:

```
addr2line -i -C -f -p -e ./server.bin 0x11a68b4ac
?? ??:0
```

How can I get info regarding line/function name?

Comment: Are you missing `-g` in the compile step (debug information)?

Comment: Same things with -g option